# Python abstract factory: two classes uses different method params

Tags: python, class, abstract

I have to know if this situation is correct

We have an abstract class with one method that requires 2 parameters:

```
class Base(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def class_method(self, param1, param2):
        pass
```

Then I have to implement 3 classes. Two of them use param1 and param2 in their method, but one of them only uses param1, I don´t need to use it inside!

```
class ClassA(Base):
    def class_method(self, param1, param2):
        return param1 + param2

class ClassB(Base):
    def class_method(self, param1, param2):
        return param1 + param2

class ClassC(Base):
    def class_method(self, param1, param2):
        return param1
```

Is this a correct implementation? What´s the best way to manage the unused param2 in the ClassC method?

I tried also to define param2 as optional

```
class Base(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def class_method(self, param1, param2=None):
        pass
```

But the question is still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example is correct. Whether or not `ClassC` uses the required parameter is irrelevant, as long as it *accepts* an argument. Consider this example:

```
lst: Base = [ClassA(), ClassB(), ClassC()]

for obj in lst:
    obj.class_method(x, y)
```

From a static typing perspective, you don't know what the actual runtime values in `lst` are, only that they are instances of (subclasses of) `Base`, and so `obj.class_method` must accept two arguments.

If you make an argument optional as in your second example, then a subclass cannot turn around and require it, for the same reasons. The following is correct given the static type of `lst`: no use of `class_method` should require a second argument.

```
lst: Base = [ClassA(), ClassB(), ClassC()]

for obj in lst:
    obj.class_method(x)
```

---

Note this is in the context of conforming to the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). For all ABC cares about, the following is "correct":

```
class ClassD(Base):
    class_method = None
```

You can assign anything you want to `class_method`, as long as it's not another abstract method, and you'll be able to instantiate `ClassD` without a problem. Whether that instance behaves properly doesn't matter.